# How to create 3 way ManyToMany relationship django

Tags: django, database-design, django-admin

Need to model the relationship between servers, applications, and server role, in django admin.

- Server can have **one** or **many applications**
- An application can be hosted on **one** or **many** servers
- A Server has one or many roles for an app (DB server role, 
  WEB server role, etc.)

  - i.e : ServerA has the role (Web server and Db server, 2 roles) for AppX
  - Server A has role of (Web server) for AppY

The code below ServerRole is the intermediary model

Here is what I am thinking. It works fine so far but am I missing something?

```
class Application(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Server(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    apps = models.ManyToMany('Application', related_name='servers')

class ServerRole(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    servers = models.ManyToMany(Server, related_name='serverrole')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your requirement correctly, this is more like what you need

```
class ServerRole(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Application(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Server(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    apps = models.ManyToMany('Application', through='ServerRole', related_name='servers')
```

Rational - A server can have many apps and an app can have many servers. if an app is on a particular server it should have only one role on it (if not your whole system because very much more complicated and harder to write) which can be implemented by the through model in a Many to Many relationship.

Comment: Trying to understand the difference between your code and mine. Your 2nd sentence states: If an app is on a particular sever it should ahve only one role on it.  This is not the CASE. One sever may have multiple roles for one particular app. Example. Server A may have the role of web server +  role of proxy server for one particular app. The SAME server A may have the role of proxy server for APP B. That is why I though my code works fine. But perhaps I am wrong. thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, this is what I meant too. If the chess app is on Server A, it should can be the proxy. But then you can't have another instance of the chess app on Server A where server A acts as the redis cache.

Comment: As an aside, not related to your project. A server that is to be a database should only be a database. No other ports should be open to it. Additionally the hardware configurations for a DB happen to be very different to a web server or a memcache or redis. So they really shouldn't be trying to be jack of all trades in a high traffic enviorenment.

Comment: Agree with your example. Will try your code see how it differes from what I have already (shown in the example above). On your 2nd point. I agree with you. It is more like, A server is both FTP and WEB for one appA and only web for AppB. I am interested to see how the your code will differ from mine. You have server model as intermediary, I have role as intermediary. Anything else that I am missing?

Comment: only other thing is to try to use SFTP instead of FTP